# Ext.util.Format.number add extra decimals

Tags: javascript, extjs, decimal

I'm using method "Ext.util.Format.number" to convert a value to string, according to a specific format.
But this method add extra (parasite) decimal.

With this code :

```
var strValue = Ext.util.Format.number(value, this.displayFormat);
```

For example if

- displayFormat = "0,000.00############"
- value = 102.15

After conversion, strValue is not equals to 102.15 but to 102.15000000000001

Is there any way to be sure that "Ext.util.Format.number" never add extra/parasite decimal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 102.15 and 102.15000000000001 are not distinguishable(*) in JavaScript, it's up to you to choose a number format that does not include that many digits. `Ext.util.Format.number` has no way to determine the *correct* output.

(*) try `102.15 === 102.15000000000001` in your javascript console - it returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

Do parseFloat(strValue) after that formatting. I think thats what you are looking for.